# Create a C program that sums up the Positive and Negative Numbers Without arrays?

Tags: c

A program that adds all positive numbers and places them in a variable
and adds all negative numbers and places them in a variable. At the end, the program should
print the values in both variables and also compute the average of both the variables. The program should end when the user types zero.

This is what I have so far.

```
int sumPositive, sumNegative;
int n, c = 1;

int main ()
{
    printf("Enter Positive integers:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (c = 1; c <=n ; c++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        sumPositive = sumPositive + n;
    }
    printf("The value of positive numbers is: %d", sumPositive);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: plz dont ask assignment question in Stackoverflow.

Comment: You have made a good start - what specific problem are you having now ?

Comment: It doesn't return a correct answer

Comment: You should not use the same variable name, `n`, for both the number of inputs and the input number.

Comment: @SunEric global variables are `0` initialized.

Comment: You're going to need to count the number of positive values as well as the sum; likewise for the negative values.  You need a loop `while ((scanf("%d", &value) == 1 && value != 0)` to meet the 'keep going until the user enters 0' requirement.  You can add the value to the appropriate sum and increment the appropriate counter on each iteration.  At the end, you can print the requisite data.  Remember that you might need a floating point calculation for the average.

Comment: Note that you should start learning _now_ to avoid global variables.  None of the those variables needs to be global; every one, therefore, should be local.  In the short term, you won't go far wrong with 'global variables bad; local variables good'.  In the medium and long terms, you learn about dynamically allocated variables too, and you recognize that some global variables are sensible, but you limit their use as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop should probably use while instead of for since you are waiting for input, not changing a loop control variable.  So:

```
int n, sumPositive = 0, sumNegative = 0;
scanf("%d", &n);
while (n != 0)
{
    //Do your calculations here
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
```

You could also reduce the times you write `scanf` by using a while(true) loop if you want:

```
int n, sumPositive = 0, sumNegative = 0;
while(true)
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == 0)
        break;
//Rest of calculations
}
```

As Jonathan Leffler pointed out, you should check the result of `scanf` to see if the value was correctly read.  The easiest way to put this in the loop is like this:

```
int n, sumPositive = 0, sumNegative = 0;
while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n != 0)//Read an n value, check that the read was successful, then check that n != 0
{
//Rest of calculations
}
```

Comment: You need to test `scanf()` itself; it tells you whether it successfully converted a value.

Comment: Note that if the user types a letter instead of a number after having typed a non-zero number, the loop will be infinite.  The correct test is `while (scanf("%d", &in) == 1 && n != 0)`.

Comment: Note that `scanf()` may return EOF when it reads to EOF, and 0 when it is not at EOF but there is a non-digit in the input (e.g. a letter).  The test for `!= EOF` is therefore incorrect; the `!= 1` test is correct (when there is a single conversion specification in the `scanf()` format string).  If you need to disambiguate EOF and other errors, then capture the return value from `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Catch!:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x;
    int sumPositive   = 0, sumNegative   = 0;
    int countPositive = 0, countNegative = 0;

    printf( "Enter positive and negative integer numbers (0 - exit): " );

    while ( scanf( "%d", &x ) == 1 && x != 0 )
    {
        if ( x < 0 )
        {
            sumNegative += x;
            countNegative++;
        }
        else
        {
            sumPositive += x;
            countPositive++;
        }
    }

    printf( "\nSum of positive numbers is %d, and their average is %d\n",
            sumPositive, countPositive == 0 ? 0 : sumPositive / countPositive );

    printf( "\nSum of negative numbers is %d, and their average is %d\n",
            sumNegative, countNegative == 0 ? 0 : sumNegative / countNegative );

    return 0;
}
```

For example if to enter

```
1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 7 -8 9 0
```

then the output will be

```
Sum of positive numbers is 25, and their average is 5

Sum of negative numbers is -20, and their average is -5
```

Comment: Nice code, but presenting a floating point average makes more sense.  Of course that could be left for the OP to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
while( n != 0) //checking if the user has entered 0 or some other number
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //here you have to check whether the entered number is postive ( >0 ) or negative ( <0 )
    //and then accordingly you have to add it to sumPositive or sumNegative,
    //hint: if else will help you
}
```

Comment: The code isn't supposed to take a count of the number of integers to be entered; it is supposed to keep going until zero is entered (or it detects EOF).

Comment: The first time around the loop, you test an uninitialized variable.  You don't test the return value from `scanf()` so you don't know when it fails to read a number.  The loop needs to be `while (scanf("%d", &in) == 1 && n != 0)`.